# Not able to run .apk from eclipse on emulator

Tags: android-emulator

When I run my android Helloworld application it won't run on emulator and get stuck with following message. Please guide me how to solve this issue.

```
[2012-04-28 12:45:56 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2012-04-28 12:45:56 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2012-04-28 12:45:56 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2012-04-28 12:45:56 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.demo.HelloAndroidActivity activity launch
[2012-04-28 12:45:56 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Hello'
[2012-04-28 12:45:56 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-04-28 12:45:57 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
```

Above is the console log appears when i run the program from eclipse window.

Comment: Looks normal... Usually the line after states that the app has run

Answer (score 0):

Looks good. Do you maybe get a "Application has quit" or something of that sort? If yes, then there's something wrong with your project that you'd have to fix.